# How to work around browser settings that prevent WordPress Dashboard Font Icons from downloading

Tags: html, css, wordpress, fonts

I have a client that is a minor, local government agency that tasked us with building two WordPress based sites. Upon completion of the first, an issue arose when they logged into the site at their offices.

**When logged into the WordPress dashboard, none of the built in font icons are working**.  This includes the WYSIWIG editor, the toolbar on the left hand side of the dashboard, and every other place that these icons are used.

The browsers the client has available are FF 17 and IE 9, with preference given to IE 9.  In either case, the font icons are not showing.  Worse, in FF they have JavaScript disabled, which has further ramifications.

Upon further investigation, my team and I have come under the impression that they have certain security settings enabled that disallow the downloading of fonts.

According to their IT professionals,  they are following "National Guidelines" that prevent them from changing any security settings, and/or installing or updating any browsers.

My goal is to find some kind of work around for this issue, such as a fallback image/icon that will load in place of the font-icons.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you post screenshots of the dashboard missing icons? I'm looking at my WP dash right now, and the icons don't look necessary to me.

Comment: As requested http://cl.ly/image/3N0P1H38460G
On my end, removing the icons didn't break the UI as you could still mouse over and get the tooltip.  Yet, according to the client, the lack of icons resulted in her not being able to click the tool buttons she needed even if she was hovering over the appropriate tool.

Comment: Oh, right. I was looking at the "text" editor. The problem is in "visual", which normal people use. Thanks for the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to apply a `display:none;` on `.dashicons-before:before` to hide all of the default icons if it would take to long to set them all individually.

It would be best to go through for each dash icon and apply the fallback image like

`.dashicons-admin-tools:before{
content: ""; /*might need an important*/
background:transparent url(image.jpg) left top no-repeat;
}`

Realistically making your own admin theme would probably be best.

Comment: Genius.  You = My Hero.  While I didn't use your answer exactly, I took your approach and created a plugin that overwrites the styles for the visual editor toolbar.  I'll update my question with the answer later.